# How to handle dynamic pricing plan table in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an app where there are four types of plans a user can buy. These plans come from the backend and after selecting a plan, the user is navigated to a page where payment is handled. This pricing table page can be viewed again but if the user has bought any plan, the button text will be changed to cancel subscription. Now I can change button text dynamically for all the other plans but if the user cancels a subscription, I do not know how to handle this dynamic button text logic.

There is a stackblitz linked but since the data is coming from the backend I cannot properly demonstrate the functionality. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6eaoi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I just need a way to change button text back to 'Choose Plan' after the user cancels a plan.

Comment: You can try reducing the code and making it less complicated like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejencq depending on your needs. I guess your object of allSubscriptions will have other data besides the ones you have in the example, so your button text method would be updated with more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the HTML you can do this:

```
<div class="perks">
  <div class="d-flex actionButton">
    <button
      type="button"
      *ngIf="planIndex === i"
      (click)="cancelSubscription(plan)">
      Cancel Subscription
    </button> 
    <button
      type="button"
      *ngIf="planIndex !== i"
      (click)="selectSubscription(plan)">

      <span *ngIf="planIndex > i"> Upgrade </span>
      <span *ngIf="planIndex < i"> Downgrade </span>
      <span *ngIf="!planIndex"> Choose plan </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you receive your subscriptions from the backend you have to do this

```
 this.planIndex = this.allSubscriptions.findIndex((sub) => sub.isSubscribed);
```

You can delete the `setDynamicButtonText` function

Explanation:

- if planIndex is null, all buttons are the same "Choose Plan"
- If we get the index of the subscribed plan, the element with the similar index has "Cancel subscrption" whatever is higher has "Downgrade" whatever is lower is to "Upgrade"

Advice:

- Never call a function to render HTML in the template it will be called infinitely and it will create bugs. [Explanation](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Comment: Thank you. I had to adjust the if conditions a little bit for when no planindex was found because findIndex method return -1 in that case. But after adjusting the conditions, it worked perfectly. 

P.S thank you for the advice. will keep that in mind.